# pacemaker IP and MAC failover

Tags: cluster, failover, pacemaker, linux-ha

I am setting up a system with two redundant servers, where one is an active one. If the active server goes down or is not reachable the other server has to become active. All the services are ready so the only required action is IP failover.

I tried to setup up the basic pacemaker cluster as described in

https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_add_a_resource.html

I have created the following resource:

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.0.10 nic=eth1 iflabel=.1 mac=02:50:56:01:01:01 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s
```

I do get the IP failover but it is on the eth1 interface and the specified address is not present in any of the interfaces.

I would need the active server to have eth1.1 created with the specified mac and IP address. I can see in the documentation that the ***mac*** parameter

> "is only used in case of the Cluster IP Alias"

I do not know what does the Cluster Ip Alias require in terms of setup/configuration.

Just for clarification the servers are placed in a custom network, where the switches previously did not update the ARP tables after moving IP addresses. I do not have access to those switches. There is a possibility that it may work with the gratuitous ARP request but there is a very limited time to setup and test the system. so I would like to have the solution with MAC failover ready in case we need it.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Versions:

centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-1062, pcs-0.9.167-3, pacemaker-1.1.20-5, resource-agents-4.1.1-30

Comment: Why do you set a `/32` mask? Should this IP bind to an existing interface with its own IP? Which versions are you using (`resource-agents`, `pacemaker`, your Linux version, etc.)?

Comment: 32 mask - copy mistake should be 24

Comment: Versions:
centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64

pcs-0.9.167-3.el7.centos.1.x86_64
pacemaker-1.1.20-5.el7_7.1.x86_64
resource-agents-4.1.1-30.el7_7.4.x86_64